# sbt ignores my scaladoc settings

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I am trying to follow the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html) for scaladoc generation. I have a multi project (i.e. aggregate with sub-projects) build which was a `./build.sbt` for general settings. I added the last entry in the following example:

```
scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")

scalacOptions in ThisBuild += "-no-specialization"

// API docs
scalacOptions in ThisBuild in (Compile,doc) ++= Seq(
  "-diagrams", "-doc-title", name.value
)
```

This doesn't have any effect. Neither does scaladoc attempt to generate diagrams, nor is the main document title set, so simply these settings are ignored. Likewise, if I add a `"-foobar"` option, no error appears.

How to fix this (in `build.sbt`, I don't want to go into `project/Build.scala`, thanks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as Josh said, somehow the `ThisBuild` / `ThisProject` stuff overwrites each other.

The solution was to migrate the `project/Build.sbt` from the sbt 0.12 times into `build.sbt`, which fortunately was mostly copy + paste, as sbt 0.13 now accepts a lot of normal Scala code in there (not `object`s, though...).

I then defined

```
lazy val commonSettings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  ...
  scalacOptions  ++= Seq(
    "-no-specialization",
    // "-Xelide-below", "INFO", // elide debug logging!
    "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature"
  ),
  // API docs:
  scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) ++= Seq(
    "-diagrams",
    "-diagrams-dot-path", "/usr/local/bin/dot",
    // "-diagrams-dot-timeout", "20", "-diagrams-debug",
    "-doc-title", name.value
  ),
  ...
)
```

And it works.

---

The last annoying bit is the requirement for `"-diagrams-dot-path"`, this truly sucks as it is an open source project, and I don't want to force that path onto anyone else. Why the heck doesn't it find `dot` on my `$PATH` which *does* include `/user/local/bin`?

Comment: OS X madness: bash `$PATH` is not seen by desktop applications. Since I run sbt from within IntelliJ IDEA, `sys.env("PATH")` is almost empty. My guess is adding `/usr/local/bin` to a `PATH` entry in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` might solve this.

Comment: This works. One must be careful to include `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in the `PATH` entry of `environment.plist`, because defining that entry otherwise overrides the default (these two paths). Afterwards, system needs reboot, and `dot` will be found by scaladoc.

Answer (score 3):

So, if you run inspect on the `doc` task, you'll find that the setting sbt is looking for is:

`scalacOptions in ThisProject in (Compile, doc)`

`ThisBuild` is reserved for things that are re-used across projects (or shared that way), like scalaVersions.

Now, the issue is that `scalacOptions in ThisProject in (Compile,doc)` will first read from `scalacOptions in ThisProject in Compile` before checking `scalacOptions in ThisProject` before going down to `ThisBuild`.

Most likely, something is specifying the scalacOptions at a higher precedence and your setting is ignored.   You should drop the `in ThisBuild` and things should work for the root project.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If I change to `in ThisProject` the result is the same—no diagrams. If I add the options directly to main scalacOptions, scaladoc produces diagrams, but the normal compilation fails because option `-diagrams` not understood. If I drop `in ThisBuild` for the main scalacOptions, they are not applied to my different sub projects. I thought the whole point of sbt settings management is that when I use `++=`, dependencies are smartly coalesced and not overwritten?

Comment: Ah, so you have subprojects?    The hierarchy of setting inherentance for scaladoc requires you to re-specify the scaladoc settings on each project.   That's perhaps a limitation of how we pull settings, but a few `inspect tree compile:doc` commands and that'll show you where we're getting the settings.

The common settings approach you list below is definitely a good one.  I'd like to merge that with this one to make sure the description of setting inheritance is included.  Does what I wrote make sense or does it need expanded?

Comment: Yes, it has subprojects. Still not sure I understand your approach. Running `inspect doc` just gives me `myroot/compile:doc::scalacOptions`. Running `inspect tree compile:doc` also doesn't make my brain understand what is going on. But yes, feel free to merge the common settings approach, it worked for me.